# Is "type in" used with computers only?

Tags: word-meaning

I was reading the definition of  "type in" and it was:

> "wrote information in computers"

If I wrote information into a phone or notebook or anything else can I use the expression "type in"?

Comment: Fatima. typing is one thing. You type with a keyboard. So anything that allows information to be entered has to be with keyboard. The notebook doesn't really work unless it's a program.

Comment: Your phone **is** a computer.  And if "notebook" means a small laptop computer, then it too is a computer.

Comment: What's the original definition quote? I'm sure it wasn't "***wrote** information in **computers***", or if it was, you need a better source for definitions.

Comment: When you say "notebook", do you mean "something made out of paper", "a notebook-format computer", or "a notebook implemented by software such as Jupyter Notes"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before computers, typing was something done on a *typewriter*. Letters were directly produced onto paper by the machine. The writing could not really be spoken of as going 'in' to anything - it just went 'on' to the paper.

This is why '*type in*' is a phrase that emerged in connection with computers. What you type on the keyboard goes *in* to the computer. In fact, in the very early days of home micro computers which came with a BASIC interpreter, software was sometimes published in books and magazines for users to type into their computer themselves and save to whatever media they used. Software distributed this way had various common names, but many called it "type-in" software.

Writing in a physical, paper notebook in handwriting is not referred to as "typing". But if you mean any kind of 'notebook' application on a modern computing device with a keyboard - even a virtual keyboard, such as on a smartphone - I suppose you *could* say you have to 'type in' the information, but I don't think it is commonly used. 'Typing' is normally thought of as a skill using both hands and a full-size keyboard. Entering text on a virtual keyboard on modern smart devices is often done using just one finger, sometimes two thumbs. Some on-screen keyboards have more innovative ways of entering text, such as 'swiping' one finger between the letters without lifting. This is not strictly 'typing' - a word that comes from the older printing technique of '*typesetting*' in which each letter was individually set in sequence.

I think the most common expressions for entering text into a smartphone would be 'wrote' (as in *I wrote a text message*) or 'put in' (eg '*I put your number in my phone*).

Comment: Agreed, but to that I would add that one used to "type in" and address etc. into a preprinted form.

Comment: I would personally use "type" for any method of entry on a phone, including swiping. "write" also seems correct, but more general. (For instance, I might apologize for a typo in a text by saying "Sorry, I can't type today".)

Comment: @Kaia I'd have to disagree... the word 'typo' is **not** derived from 'typing'. It is short for 'typographical error', and while the shared etymology of both words is quite obvious, 'typing' and 'typography' are both very different skills. The use of 'typo' has been extended over time to cover all kinds of mistakes that lead to an error in written text. But it is over-used as an excuse for spelling errors. My point is, a valid context where you could use 'typo' does not necessarily mean you must be 'typ*ing*'.

Comment: @Astralbee The point I was trying to convey isn't anything to do with the word typo itself, though thanks for the fun etymology. It's that I'd personally say "i can't type" on a phone, not "i cant write" or "i can't text". Obviously the other options are also correct. I might also say "ugh, typing on a phone is so slow, let me grab my laptop", and in that context it's clear that there's nothing about typos.

Answer (score 3):

"type" has a broader meaning, meaning "printed letters", i.e. individual letters that are reused, just like the text you are reading right now.
This was originally done via typesetting, i.e. slowly putting metal blocks in order to print a word. Later, we started using keyboards (including typewriters - hence the name "type writer") to create our types on the fly, as opposed to a slow process of aligning heavy blocks.

"typing in" specifically refers to using a keyboard to select your types (discrete letter characters). In my interpretation of the word, this does not restrict the usage to physical keyboard such as typewriters or computer keyboards; it also allows for virtual touch keyboards.

The distinguishing feature here is that when you are typing something in, you are pressing buttons on a button board which correspond to individual ready-made characters.
Whether it's a physical computer keyboard, virtual smartphone keyboard, ... is an irrelevant distinction.

This is different from calligraphy, which is handwritten.

*Just to cover an edge case: if you write discrete characters by hand, it's arguable whether or not it's calligraphy (I don't think it is but it's not relevant to pursue an answer here), but it's definitely not "typing in", and that's the only relevant consideration for this particular answer.*

> if I wrote information in the phone or notebook or anything else can I call it "type in"

If by "write" you mean using pen and paper, no. If you mean writing using a digital pen, then still no. The key decider here is that these are forms of calligraphy.
As I mentioned before, even though a set of printed letters can be called a "type" in the classic sense of the word, writing them by hand is still not "typing it in", so the answer is still no.

If you mean using "buttons on a button board which correspond to individual ready-made characters", then yes.

Pedantic edge case: if you used a digital pen to press keys on a virtual keyboard, or a physical pen to press keys on a keyboard, that's still "typing it in". The focus here isn't what you're using to press the key, it's that the text is being composed by pressing a sequence of keys (whether physically or figuratively).

Comment: To which I'd add Linotype and Monotype typesetting machines. The history or at least terminology of keyboards is interesting: even in English "small things to be pressed" have variously been referred to as keys, buttons and studs before settling on "key" for typewriters and computer keyboards and "button" for industrial control panels etc.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd it gets worse:  additional keys for controlling audio/video playback on a keyboard are sometimes referred to as "media buttons" (along with "media keys").  Of course they're often a different shape to the normal typing keys

Comment: @ChrisH undoubtedly :-) Interestingly, words I've never seen used in this context are "latch" and "trigger"... I suspect that "key" was a natural choice for letters etc. on a keyboard since (a) the earliest teletypes looked rather like small pianos and (b) pianos etc. have similar "side-to-side compressed" mechanisms.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd I'd be surprised (though not very) to see "latch", due to its related meaning to do with a button that stays pushed

Comment: @ChrisH... and of course that's how typewriter shift-lock originally worked. However by definition they'd have to have decided on the term for what was pressed (i.e. a button/stud/key) before they could decide how to latch/lock it :-)

Answer (score 3):

The phrase “type in” means on some kind of device with a keyboard.  Mechanical typewriters (and adding machines, keypresses, and so on) are now obsolete.

However you can still “type in” numbers on a cash register, for example.

Comment: I've not heard of its being used for a cash register, although I suspect "punch in" might have been.

Comment: There might in fact be a distinction to be made between older adding machines and cash registers where there were ten keys per column which could be depressed in any order and were released when the operation lever was pulled, and newer ones with a dozen or so keys in total on which a number had to be typed in the correct sequence. Photos of the former type at https://www.si.edu/spotlight/adding-machines/full-keyboard-burroughs (Smithsonian) for youngsters :-)